# Adding count to a vector while looping through dataframe

Tags: arrays, r, string, for-loop, count

I am relatively new in R. I'm working on a project in which there is a column of IDs (PMID), a column of MESH terms which are basically a lot of biomedical summarized terms (MH), and a column for year that's organized sequentially (EDAT_Year). My goal is to create a vector that holds the count of a particular word from the MESH terms for each year. Basically, if a row contains the word (not how many times it's in the row but rather its presence), it should be counted and separated by year in the vector.

Here is an example. Suppose this is the dataframe:

```
  PMID    MH                            EDAT_Year
  1       Male, Lung, Heart, Aneurysm   1978
  2       Male, Male, Anemia, Lung      1978
  3       Heart, Anemia, Adult          1980
  4       Female, Heart, Blood, Acute   1980
  5       Male, Blood, Adult, Lung      1980
  6       Male, Kidney, Brain, Heart    1983
  7       Male, Lung, Blood, Male       1983
```

Then, if I were to test "Male", I would want the output to be

```
  2 1 2
```

to represent that there are 2 observations in 1978 that contain "Male", 1 in 1980, and 2 in 1983 (regardless of how many times it has appeared).

I am currently working with 3 years, but hope to expand to more. I was able to do this manually with 3 years with the following (years are 1978, 1980, 1983 by the way) in which I created multiple columns that only contained MESH terms if they belonged to that year:

```
# count occurrences in the three years
disease_78 <- length(grep("\\Male\\>", total$MH_78))
disease_80 <- length(grep("\\Male\\>", total$MH_80))
disease_83 <- length(grep("\\Male\\>", total$MH_83))
```

But now I am trying to write a function so that if I were to enter a phrase, I would get all the occurrences in one vector, instead of manually having to copy and paste or having hundreds of columns for each year. This is what I have so far:

```
# function of count occurences
count_fxn <- function(x)
{
  # read in argument as character
  phrase_to_count <- deparse(substitute(x))

  # create a vector to store count values
  count_occur <- numeric(0)

  # a vector for how many years there are
  num_years <- seq(1, 3, 1)

  # loop through entire data frame
  for (i in 1:length(total$PMID))
  {
    # loop through the three years
    for(j in 1:length(num_years))
    {
      # if at least one occurence occurs in row cell, increment count
      if (length(grep(phrase_to_count, total$MH[i]) > 0))
      {
        count_occur[j] <- count_occur[j] + 1
      }
      # if the next row's year is different than the current one's, move to 
      # next spot for next year in vector
      if (total$EDAT_Year[i] != total$EDAT_Year[i+1])
      {
        j <- j + 1
      }
      # increment so go to next line to read in data
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  return(count_occur) 
}
# using function
count_fxn(Male)
```

But this is the error I keep getting:

```
 Error in if (total$EDAT_Year[i] != total$EDAT_Year[i + 1]) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

When I change

```
if (total$EDAT_Year[i] != total$EDAT_Year[i + 1])
```

to

```
if (total$EDAT_Year[j] != total$EDAT_Year[j + 1])
```

I don't get any errors, but instead, the output is

```
NA NA NA
```

when it should be something like

```
3453 2343 5235
```

to represent how many observations contained "Male" in them, in the years 1978, 1980, and 1983 respectively.

Please advise. I'm not the strongest coder yet, and I've been working on this for 2 hours when I'm sure it could've been done in much less time.

Comment: Please include a minimum working example with data so it is easier to answer your question?  Also I would not do this in a for loop, in R this can be accomplished without a for loop and it will run much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added sample data and what the output should be like. And how else would I accomplish this, if not a for loop? Thanks, Ian.

Comment: R is vectorized - operations are preformed across all elements of a vector.  Most of the time when you would reach for a for loop it is a good sign there is a better way to do something in R.  As you are new to R here is one of my favorite introduction to R references: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `by()`.

```
with(df, lengths(by(MH, EDAT_Year, grep, pattern="Male")))
# EDAT_Year
# 1978 1980 1983 
#    2    1    2
```

Comment: My goodness you condensed like 30+ lines of code into 1...how simple and sweet. Thank you! Since you're so efficient, how would I be able to return the indices of where "Male" appears?

Comment: @sweetmusicality - Thanks.  Do you mean the indices for each string, as in 1 and 3 for `Male, Kidney, Male, Heart`?  Or just the rows where `Male` appears, which is `grep("Male", df$MH)`?

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I meant the latter, and I was able to figure it out before your answer so yay I'm progressing on my journey in becoming somewhat more comfortable with R hah.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of occurrences of every "word" in `MH` for every year without having to type out each word or create a list of words you can do so as follows:

```
DF <- read.table(text="PMID    MH   EDAT_Year
1       Male,Lung,Heart,Aneurysm   1978
2       Male,Male,Anemia,Lung      1978
3       Heart,Anemia,Adult          1980
4       Female,Heart,Blood,Acute   1980
5       Male,Blood,Adult,Lung      1980
6       Male,Kidney,Brain,Heart    1983
7       Male,Lung,Blood,Male       1983", header=T)

DF <- DF %>% 
  #Convert MH column to nested list
  dplyr::mutate(MH = strsplit(as.character(MH), ",")) %>% 
  #reashape data into tidy format
  tidyr::unnest(MH) %>% 
  #eliminate duplicates to not count PMIDs with multiple identical entries in MH
  unique() %>% 
  #count entries for each value in MH by year
  reshape2::dcast(EDAT_Year ~ MH) 

DF
```

Results in:

```
  EDAT_Year Acute Adult Anemia Aneurysm Blood Brain Female Heart Kidney Lung Male
1      1978     0     0      1        1     0     0      0     1      0    2    2
2      1980     1     2      1        0     2     0      1     2      0    1    1
3      1983     0     0      0        0     1     1      0     1      1    1    2
```

Comment: Thanks! If I need to use this data form, I'll be sure to refer to your code. This is neat!